# Cross compile to Windows from Linux with Allegro-5

Tags: c++, linux, windows

How can I compile a C++ program that uses Allegro-5 lib with command line?

For example with `g++`, I write this:

`g++ -std=c++14 -o mouse mouse.cpp $(pkg-config --cflags --libs allegro-5 allegro_dialog-5)`

Now, I want to compile the same source for Windows (`.exe`), so I installed `mingw-w64`:

`sudo apt-get install mingw-w64`

And found this instructions:

```
# C
i686-w64-mingw32-gcc hello.c -o hello32.exe      # 32-bit
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc hello.c -o hello64.exe    # 64-bit

# C++
i686-w64-mingw32-g++ hello.cc -o hello32.exe     # 32-bit
x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ hello.cc -o hello64.exe   # 64-bit
```

So I try to compile my source like this:

`i686-w64-mingw32-g++ -std=c++14 -o mouse mouse.cpp $(pkg-config --cflags --libs allegro-5 allegro_dialog-5)`

And gave me this error:

`mouse.cpp:2:30: fatal error: allegro5/allegro.h: No existe el archivo o el directorio
compilation terminated.`

Source(line 2,3):

```
#include <allegro5/allegro.h>
#include <allegro5/allegro_native_dialog.h>
```

So, how can I compile an exe from Linux with `mingw-w64`?

Comment: You have to build the allegro-5 library with the same toolchain and link against it. Sources are here: http://liballeg.org/download.html